# How to manage a set of private patches while working on new features?

Tags: git

I'm working with this legacy code which I need to introduce some new features.

Problem is that it imposes some ergonomic problems, like some very slow pages and bad logging messages.

I can solve those problems, but it has no unit tests so I cannot be sure my fixes really stand by themselves if I push them to production. They would not be approved either, as those parts are not really connected to the new features.

Sometimes, it's just my comments I made to better understand the code.

So, my workflow has been:

- Dig deep in the code, make some comments, include some logging.
- Fix some very slow parts, just enough as the path from logon to the feature I'm working on is fast and I can iterate quicker.
- Carefully commit those small changes to a "my" branch.

So, when I need to work on a new feature:

- Pull development branch (shared with others)
- Rebase "my" to the development (important to the next step)
- Branch "feature" branch from "my" (feature tip is now development + my changes)
- Create the feature code changes
- Rebase "feature" from "my" onto "development" (git rebase --onto development my)
- Merge "feature" into "development"

If I need to make other fixes in unrelated parts of the code while working on the "feature" branch:

- git stash unfinished changes (worktree is now "feature" HEAD)
- checkout "my"
- make the small change and commit
- rebase "feature" to the new "my"
- checkout "feature"
- unstash the unfinished changes

As you may think, this is a pita, but better safe than sorry.

So, what I wanted was:

- have some sort of patch system
- make a small change (as a new log message)
- make a patch out of it
- keep working and committing my feature changes
- unapply the patches
- merge "feature" with "development"
- make a "other feature" branch out of "development"
- apply patches
- repeat

Does anyone managed to find a good way to deal with it? Some sort of patch management system?

[Stacked Git](https://stacked-git.github.io) seems to be a nice tool, but I couldn't find a way to save patches to apply into another branch.

- git switch development
- git checkout -B feature
- stg init
- how to bring my patches from thy "my" branch? (or any other place they can be stored at?)

Comment: Why not make a script that cherry pick your private patch ?

Comment: My current workflow is basically that, just instead of cherry picking a set of "my" commits, I "cherry-pick" them all (rebase them to development and then branch from them) and then "revert" them (rebase parent back to development, basically deleting them from the feature branch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is already solved with the way you handle it already. Maybe a real solution is to actually incorporate some or all of your improvements/changes into the mainline (if even possible, up to management/team).

Apart from that, a couple of workarounds are to work only with stashes, or to work on top of `my` branch and then `rebase -i` and just move the `feature` commits an the beginning of the branch, or another possible solution is to create your own [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) files and apply then where and when necessary.

##### Disclaimer - this solutions might not bring you the benefit you were looking for, it's just an alternative.

---

#### Option 0 - stashing

Just stash all your `my` changes and then apply them to each `feature` you work on. `git add -p` just want you need to and then discard the rest of the changes. This is flexible as you would see conflicts when they arise and you don't have to manage and rebase your `my` branch all the time.

You can always change your stashes are modify them and create new stashes (dropping old obsolete ones)

The negative here is that working with stashes is sometimes difficult when it comes to conflict resolution. Another not so nice thing is that you always have dangling stashes and if they are a lot, managing them might be difficult.

#### Option 1 - rebasing

Here you still have your `my` branch. When you need to work on a feature, just work on your `my` branch. Once done:

```sh
git rebase -i HEAD~N
```

And them move your `feature` changes at the beginning and your improvement changes should be the latest commits. Now the state of the code should be exactly the same, but with differently ordered commits. All you need to do is checkout the commits that is before your `my` changes/improvements and create a `feature` branch.

```sh
# Go to your last feature commit
git checkout 3ab959ba
# Create a branch off of that
git switch -c my-feature
```

You're all done. You can push your changes.

##### Note - this is not much different from the current approach you are taking

You would still need to rebase your `my` changes constantly to keep up to date with `develop`.

---

#### Option 2 - patches

You can create patch files which you can save locally and apply them whenever you want.

Example:

```sh
git format-patch -2 HEAD --stdout > 0001-my-patch.patch
```

Would create a patch from the last two commits starting from `HEAD`. If you create a patch for your `my` branch then you can take all those changes into a single `*.patch` file.

Then once you start working on a `feature` you can do the following:

```sh
# Check that the patch won't produce errors
git apply --check 0001-my-patch.patch

# Apply the patch without actually making the patches into commits
git apply -- 0001-my-patch.patch
```

Now you just have a working directory with unstaged changes from your patch. You can start working on your feature. Once you are done, commit only the changes for that feature without touching the patch changes (ex: using `git add -p` to add only what you need). Commit and then re-apply the patch in reverse.

```sh
git apply -R 0001-my-patch.patch
```

Then you won't see the changes from your initial patch apply.

---

##### This will break in the following scenarios

- If you touch the patch changes.
- If your `feature` changes are way to close to your patch changes and you can't separate them (through `git add -p` for instance).
- If you add changes *between* the patch changes, thus causing the `git apply -R` invalid (you can discard the changes of your patch, but then you won't be able to apply it again...).

So basically, this method is useful if your improvements won't interact with any other feature changes.

Comment: Great answer. The reordering of commits seems like a good ideia. The patch could be, but trying to isolate changes to commit (stage by chunk) has bites me more than enough so that I know I can’t do it without accidentally forgetting something.

Comment: I would also suggest going for stashing, if that is even possible in your specific case